# hierarchy of nested divs has unintended overlapping borders when using margin and padding

Tags: css, xhtml

When nesting `<div>`'s their `margin`'s and `padding`'s start to overlap. What I understood from [the spec's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) the `margin`, `border` and `padding` are just part of the space an element takes and each element should stay contained in the content-area of parent `<div>`.

Clearly I understand wrong, but I hope somebody can explain me right.

Bottom-line: please help me let the `thingy`'s stay inside the `top`. Preferably in a natural (not too hacky) way.

Thanks for reading and any insight you can share in advance!

#### The Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WrasM/2/

#### The HTML (making sure newlines in HTML don't have any influence):

```
<!--
--><div class="parent"><!--
    --><div class="top"><!--
        --><div class="thingy">label 1</div><!--
        --><div class="thingy">label 2</div><!--
        --><div class="thingy">label 3</div><!--
    --></div><!--
    --><div class="bottom"><!--
        -->some test content<!--
    --></div><!--
--></div><!--
-->
```

#### The CSS:

```
.parent {  display: block;
           margin: 0px;  padding: 0px;
           border: 3px solid Yellow; }
.top {  display: block;
        margin: 0px;  padding: 0px; }
.thingy {  display: inline;
           margin: 20px;  padding: 10px;
           border: 1px solid DarkBlue; }
.bottom {  display: block;
           margin: 0px;  padding: 0px;
           border: 1px solid DarkBlue; }
```

#### The result:

[image: fiddle_result.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.thingy` to `display:inline-block`.

Section `8.3` on this spec page http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html says
`These properties have no effect on non-replaced inline elements.` for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just didn't see it... Got `dfghjk` on my forehead as a result of the banging... Thanks for the rescue, marking as answer.